# move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a form with 3 tabs, one for pictures, one for music and one for youtube.
The first 2 are forms where people can upload files, the second is just for a youtube link.

When people hit the 'upload' button they are sent to a second page where the actual uploading is done. Now uploading musc works, but using the same code for the pictures it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitfoto'])) {
    // uploaden
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . time() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    // Here I do a bunch of stuff with the database, but it never gets that far.    
    echo "Thanks for uploading this file.";

    } else{ echo "File upload failed";} }
```

Now I get File upload failed all the time. But the exact same code seems to work for uploading .mp3 file.

How is this possible?

Comment: Try checking what $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] has?

Comment: what does `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` show in your `else` block?

Comment: @JoseVega - great minds think alike!  or...maybe it's just we've been burnt enough times doing file uploads in PHP that we instinctively write "check `$FILES[...]['error']`" ;)

Comment: Please put better question title..