# Retrieve filename extension for multiple uploaded files (Class Upload, PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, class, file-upload

Language: **PHP** / Using [**Class Upload** by Colin Verot](http://www.verot.net/download/class.upload.php/class.upload.txt)
About: **Multiple Uploading**

The code below already uploads the files fine, it works...
**PROBLEM: I am having trouble figuring out how to get the filename *extension***.
(In a comment below, I have specified where my problem area is...)

```php
// CONNECTION TO DATABASE HERE...

// INCLUDE UPLOAD CLASS LIBRARY
include (dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/class.upload.php');

$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['fileupload'] as $k => $l)
{
    foreach ($l as $i => $v)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
        $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
        $imagename = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
    }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {

            // THIS IS MY PROBLEM AREA, GETTING FILE EXTENSION
            $ext=strchr($imagename,".");

            $generate_name = rand(100,99999); 
            $generate_name_extra = rand(200,9999);
            $filenamex = "PHOTO_".$generate_name.$generate_name_extra."_".time();
            $filenamex_thumb = $filenamex."_thumb";

            // COMPLETE FILENAME WITH EXTENSION
            $filename = $filenamex.strtolower($ext);
            $handle = new upload($file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
            ///// 1 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $handle->file_new_name_body   = $filenamex_thumb;
            $handle->image_resize         = true;
            $handle->image_x              = '300';
            $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
            $handle->jpeg_quality = '100';

            // ABSOLUTE PATH BELOW
            $handle->process($absoRoot.'covers/thumbs/');

            if ($handle->processed) {

            // SUCCESSFUL RESPONSE

        }
      else
        {

         // FAILED RESPONSE

        }     
    }
}
```

And the webform is:

```php
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="fileupload[]" id="fileupload" type="file" multiple>
```

I really pretty much need the file extensions to serve the files correctly online, but I can't spot where to find it. I have tried using: `$files[$i][$k]` instead of `$imagename` in my specified *problem area* above, as well as `$file` and other possible solutions, but I can't spot which one's going to give me the filename with extension.

Hopefully someone could point it out. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: That is exactly my question. In my code above (where I have made a comment) I have shown my *problem area* which is where the splitting of the filename + extension is supposed to happen. Thing is, I can't figure out why `$imagename` is not working. I use that for a single upload & it works, whereas with this instance it doesn't.

Comment: In PHP an uploaded file is not always an uploaded file. Try to see there are any errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938408/move-uploaded-file/10938669#10938669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ext=array_pop(explode('.', $imagename));
```

Comment: This doesn't work with my code above either. Image file would return as `filnamearray` instead of expected `filename.jpg`

Comment: **print_r($ext)** see what $ext contains

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking, I tried `$image = $_FILES['fileupload']['name']; $imagename=array_pop($image);` and used `$ext=strchr($imagename,".");` and it worked! :) it was the **array_pop** that did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$pathdata = pathinfo($filename);
$extension = $pathdata['extension'];
```